# How to give an app access to Accounts that was previously denied?

Tags: macos, social-framework

I've been playing with Accounts framework and during my tests I've denied the app access to Accounts. Now the following code returns Denied each time I run it.

```
[[self accountStore] requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        accounts = [[self accountStore] accountsWithAccountType:twitterType];
    } else if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to list Twitter accounts %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Access denied");
    }
}];
```

What sucks is I have no clue where to reset it and googling doesn't help. I've seen how to fix it on iOS but I'm running a Mac app and the solution doesn't apply.

The Account Framework API documentation is not helpful at all.

Palm face.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out, I've found a file with my app id called **"~/Library//Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db"**

It's a sqlite3 file, so run **sqlite3 "~/Library//Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db"** then search for your app in **"access" table**, delete the row and should you have access again.

If that doesn't help there's also a file called **~/Library/Accounts/Accounts3.sqlite**, there **ZAUTHORIZATION table** which includes your app.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution no longer works, because of high-profile hacks made by big companies and others. This solution has never been supported and is an invitation to hackers. The right way to do this is using the tool provided by Apple: `tccutil`.

Thus, do the following:

1. Open `Terminal`.
2. Run `tccutil reset <service> [bundle_id]`, in which `<service>` can be `AddressBook` or `Calendar` or `All` with the optional ID of the bundle you want to reset.

Example:

```
tccutil reset All com.apple.Terminal
```